# Onsen UI Tutorial Page

Tags: onsen-ui

[image]

I'd like to do the above app Tutorial effect using Onsen UI.
However, in the [Page Patterns of Onsen UI](https://onsen.io/patterns.html), I didn't see anything similar.
Could someone shed some light on this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a carousel. You can make one using the `<ons-carousel>` component.

In this case you want to have a swipeable fullscreen carousel so you can define it like this:

```
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen>
  <ons-carousel-item>
    Content #1
  </ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item>
    Content #2
  </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

Here is a simple example of a fullscreen carousel:
http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/xbbzOQ

Please also take a look at the docs:
http://onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html

If you want bullets, you can use the `carousel.getActiveCarouselItemIndex()` in order to get the current active element.

```
<ons-carousel-cover>
  <div class="bullets">
    <span 
      ng-repeat="idx in indices"
      ng-class="{'active': idx === carousel.getActiveCarouselItemIndex()}">
      •
    </span>
  </div>
</ons-carousel-cover>
```

You also need to trigger a digest event to make Angular understand that something changed.

This is the code:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/RWomrz

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andreas! 
btw, could you give me a hint about the progress bar (several white spots) when swiping the carousel?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/RWomrz

I will add it to the answer.

Comment: OMG, this is it!
You really save my day!